# Is it possible to change the menu bar's height?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

The latest MacBook Pro have a notch on the top of their screen. For some reason, on those machines, Apple decided to crank up the height of the menu bar.

I don't like the new height and would like to keep the old one.

Is there a way to change the height of the menu bar to get back to the original one?

[image: Comparison of Monterey Desktop on new notched MacBook and regular mac]

Note that the new menu bar is *taller* than the notch. I would
like to make the navbar the exact same height as the notch.

Comment: I'd assume the reasoning behind making it taller is to prevent the notch from encroaching onto the usable desktop and application window space? I believe there's programs already out there, which blackouts the strip along the top of the screen to the height of the notch, lowering the menu bar to below the notch. Doing so, would mean using the display size of the previous generation's of MacBook's 14" & 16" display sizes and not that extra bit of display at the top

Comment: @AVelj - that's ["Scale to fit below built-in camera"](https://support.apple.com/HT212842) which moves the menu bar. idk if it resizes too.

Comment: The menubar height is 36 pixels (scaled?) on my 16" M1, and 26 px on my Apple Thunderbolt display, on a 2018 Mini. However, given the difference in pixel density, they look almost identical. The notch extends 32 pixels, so if you have the menubar less than that, the notch would extend into the display. I'd be very surprised if Apple accommodated user adjustment of the menubar.

Comment: Same question about small gap below the navbar. They both just steal screen space :(

Comment: Use Topnotch app. Doesn't change it's size, but at least makes it invisible :)

Comment: Another reason why this might be relevant, is due to the fact that when setting "Automatically hide and show the menu bar" in desktop, the menu bar is slightly smaller than when it is not hiding, and someone might dislike the inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to change the menubar's height using any Apple-provided settings or configuration tools.

Answer (score 1):

So far, the only place you can go to change the menu bar's size is at System Settings > Acessibility > Display > Text - Menu bar size.
[image]

But unfortunately the new design/OSx makes the bar too thick.

As mentioned by [@Fede E.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/420897/fede-e), the [Top Notch app](https://topnotch.app/) does a decent job hiding the bar by adding a black bar around it..
[image]