# Change the menu bar's height

Tags: macos, mac-mini, menu-bar, monterey

The latest MacBook Pro has a notch on the top of the screen. Due to this, Apple changed the height of the menu bar. I actually prefer the taller menu bar, but don't use a MacBook Pro. I use a Mac mini. Is there a way to change the height to the new one?

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429853/is-it-possible-to-change-the-menu-bars-height